# Error 2009 when restoring iPhone

Tags: itunes, iphone, restore, error

I have a jailbreaked iPhone 4 and I updated from version 5 to v6 in wifi.

The screen shows only the recovery mode, but when I connect it to iTunes, it detects the iPhone but needs to update it.

When I restore it to the last version or to v6 I get a `restore error 2009`

I tried with 2 different computers (win7-8) and 2 different cables, but I still get this `2009` error.

I tried to enter DFU mode with redsnow but it didn't work, as the power button doesn't work, and it showed again the recovery mode.

Any thought ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try entering DFU mode by using the DFU IPSW feature with redsn0w.

From what I understand it will create an IPSW and you can click Shift+Restore in iTunes, point to the IPSW redsn0w made and iTunes will put your device in DFU mode.

From there you can try restoring normally with iTunes.

[image: Redsn0w]